# Is it possible to get warning when new version of internal library?

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory, sbt-plugin

Is there a sbt plugin or piece of code which I could use to give me warning when I compile using outdated internal libraries ?

Let's say another team have updated their library but I am still using the old one. 
The plugin could check against artifactory to see if a new one exist and if it does, give me a compilation warning.

Anyone have heard of such system ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not done it, but I think you can use [**scala-stedward**](https://github.com/fthomas/scala-steward) for that. I am not sure about the warning, but I will create PRs every time an update is available. - And, if I am not wrong, that _bot_ is built over an **SBT** _plugin_ that checks for dependencies updates, so you may only need that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

While a compiler warning is a nice solution, you might wanna look at a simpler one – [signing up for a watch in Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Watches) on the path of the library you want to get updated about. Every time a new file is deployed (new version is promoted to the release repository), you'll get an email.